# To Implement XML Editor with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am working on AngularJS based web application. I want to implement XML Editor in my application. I tried to find out the solution unfortunately, didn't any solution.
Can anyone help to do the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There have some editors to add your applications

> [Sublime](https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-sublime-package)
>
> [Atom](https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-Atom)
>
> [TextMate](https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS.tmbundle)
>
> [Brackets](https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-brackets)

Hope it helps